# Encountering "java.net.ConnectException: A route to the remote host is not available" when hitting Azure endpoint

Tags: java, azure, security, websphere

I have two servers (model and production) on which the code is deployed. The code was working fine as long it was on the model but as soon as it was deployed on production I am getting an exception.

I am using `JDK 1.8` with `okhttp` and `okhttp-urlconnection` jars of versions `3.4.2` . Can I do something from Java code so that i can give it required access? do you guys have something else in mind?

I think it might be some firewall issue.

```java
String eventGridEndpoint =String.format("https://%s/",new URI(URL).getHost());

client.publishEvents(eventGridEndpoint, eventsList); // eventList has request data sent to azure endopint.
```

The **exception** I am getting when hitting the azure endpoint is

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to 'URL' "
 caused by "java.net.ConnectException: A route to the remote host is not available."
```

Comment: Check your NSG (Network Security Groups) in Azure, or the firewall on the OS.  Clearly this is a network issue, assuming your service is running and the port it in LISTEN mode.

Comment: @Nic3500, Can i do something from Java code which will give it all the required access?

Comment: Nope, this is configured in azure.  Well you could code calls to the CLI, but then you need admin access anyway.

Comment: Definitely a system network routing issue. Nothing you can do in Java or WebSphere. Test connectivity from a command-line/shell and get that working, then the app will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and the solution

There was no TCP route set up to go to the IP address. After adding it in the system route table, we were able to connect.